# TCPDF is indenting the first line of output

Tags: tcpdf

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require '../../vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'in', [6,4]);
#$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
#$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 14);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetXY(0.5, 0.2);
$pdf->Write(0, "Hello\nworld");
$pdf->Output('Postcards-'.date('Y-m-d').'.pdf', 'I');
```

And here is the output (ignore border)

[image]

If I enter several lines, only the first is indented. Why? and how do I stop this?

Comment: Workaround: start all output with `\n` at the beginning and move the vertical position up to compensate.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would consider using `MultiCell()` function to write data to fixed place as you probably need. It handles quite much all these problems that the low-level function `Write()` does not. The below line works like a charm:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, "Hello\nworld");
```

If you really need to use `Write()`, the actual problem the line above

```
$pdf->SetXY(0.5, 0.2);
```

Commenting that out makes it working again. To understand what is going on there, the new line returns the cursor back to the start of the line **defined by the page regions and margins, not below the previous location of the cursor.

You have much better control of this when you work with the `Cells()`. You can notice it can accept `$ln` argument of values `0` to `2`, where the value `2` positions the cursor below the box regardless the regions/margins.